# Using write() to print to console

Tags: c

So I am trying to create a function that uses the write() system call (printf and other options are not available) to output the string to the console. However, I hit a snag.

Here is my function:

```
static void doPrint (const char *s)
{
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, s, sizeof(s));
}
```

Which is being called by:

> doPrint ("Hello World!\n");

However, it only prints out:

> Hello Wo

What am I doing wrong?

Note: access to stdlib and stdio is restricted

Thanks

Comment: You're lucky to have 64 bit compiler... With a 32 bit compiler, it would be just `Hell` to use `sizeof` that way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context `sizeof` doesn't do what you want - it yields the size of the pointer, not the size of the string. Use `strlen` instead.

> but access to the stdlib is restricted

You can roll your own using a `while` and a counter. Untested:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (*s++)
        len++;

    return len;
}
```

or the slightly more efficient version:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char* s)
{
   const char *end = s;
   while (*end++) {};
   return end-s-1;
}
```

The above works because the pointer is advanced to the last position in the string and then the size is the difference between the last pointer location and the first pointer location, minus 1 of course to handle the null-terminating character.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use that, but access to the stdlib is restricted.

Comment: Nitpicking: Using pointer arithmetic `my_strlen` would be slightly more efficient with this code: `const char *end=s; while (*end++) {}; return end-s-1;`

Comment: @hyde I was actually thinking of using that but though it would be less understandable (I was lazy, really). Feel free to edit my post.

Comment: @cnicutar Nah, you're right, the clearer version is perhaps better as the answer, and that marginally more efficient version is better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `sizeof`. You need to pass in the size explicitly or use `strlen`. It is taking the size of the pointer. `strlen` only works on null-terminated strings though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `sizeof` a pointer variable is the length of the pointer variable.  You want `strlen(s)` to discover how many characters are at the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `sizeof(s)`. The number of characters you want to print is the length of the string, not the size of the pointer to the first character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a pointer, not an array, so you're only printing the first `sizeof(char *)` bytes (it happens to be 8 in this case - you're probably using a 64-bit system).

You have to find the length of the string using `strlen()`:

```
write (STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));
```

You should also read [this document](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Answer (score 0):

`write (STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));` assuming your string is null-terminated.